# Unit of Work with Generic Repository Pattern MVVM, vol. 2

Tags: c#, sqlite, mvvm

Continuation of this question: [Unit of Work with Generic Repository Pattern MVVM](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36523/unit-of-work-with-generic-repository-pattern-mvvm)

I have made some modifications:

- Interfaces aren't forced to implement IDisposable
- Removed the finalizers
- Rebuilt UoW

**FeedRepository:**

```
internal class FeedRepository<T> : IFeedRepository<T>, IDisposable 
    where T: IBaseFeed, new()
{
    private readonly SQLiteConnection _db;
    private IList<T> _feeds;

    private bool _isDisposed = false;

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _feeds.Count;
        }
    }

    public FeedRepository(SQLiteConnection db)
    {
        this._db = db;
        this._feeds = _db.Table<T>().ToList();
    }

    public void Add(T feed)
    {
        this._feeds.Add(feed);
        this._db.Insert(feed);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return this._feeds;
    }

    public T GetFeedById(int id)
    {
        return this._feeds.Where(feed => int.Equals(feed.Id, id)).Single();
    }

    public T GetFeedByLink(string feedLink)
    {
        return this.GetFeedByLink(new Uri(feedLink));
    }

    public T GetFeedByLink(Uri feedLink)
    {
        return this._feeds.Where(feed => Uri.Equals(feed.Link, feedLink)).Single();
    }

    public int GetFeedIdByLink(string feedLink)
    {
        return this.GetFeedIdByLink(new Uri(feedLink));
    }

    public int GetFeedIdByLink(Uri feedLink)
    {
        return this._feeds.Where(feed => Uri.Equals(feed.Link, feedLink)).Select(feed => feed.Id).Single();
    }

    public void Remove(T feed)
    {
        this._feeds.Remove(feed);
        this._db.Delete(feed);
    }

    public void RemoveById(int id)
    {
        this.Remove(this.GetFeedById(id));
    }

    public void Update(T feed)
    {
        int indexOfFeed = this._feeds.IndexOf(this.GetFeedById(feed.Id));
        this._feeds[indexOfFeed] = feed;

        this._db.Update(feed);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (!this._isDisposed)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                if (this._db != null)
                {
                    this._db.Dispose();
                }
            }

            this._isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**IUnitOfWork:**

```
internal interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Commit();
    void Rollback();
}
```

**UnitOfWork:**

```
internal class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private readonly SQLiteConnection _db;

    private FeedRepository<FeedData> _feedDataRepository;
    private FeedRepository<FeedItem> _feedItemRepository;

    private bool _isDisposed = false;

    public FeedRepository<FeedData> FeedDataRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return _feedDataRepository;
        }
        set
        {
            _feedDataRepository = value;
        }
    }

    public FeedRepository<FeedItem> FeedItemRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return _feedItemRepository;
        }
        set
        {
            _feedItemRepository = value;
        }
    }

    public UnitOfWork(SQLiteConnection db)
    {
        this._db = db;
        this._feedDataRepository = new FeedRepository<FeedData>(this._db);
        this._feedItemRepository = new FeedRepository<FeedItem>(this._db);

        this._db.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        this._db.Commit();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        this._db.Rollback();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (!this._isDisposed)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                if (this._db != null)
                {
                    this._db.Dispose();   
                }
            }

            this._isDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I still have no idea how to remove `this._feeds = _db.Table<T>().ToList();` from the repository, because when I delete it, I can't use `GetAll()`, `GetFeedById()` and so on.

***Edit***

That's
**IBaseFeed:**

```
public interface IBaseFeed
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
    Uri Link { get; set; }
    string Misc { get; set; }
}
```

If I don't use IBaseFeed I won't take advantage of using:

```
    public T GetFeedByLink(Uri feedLink)
    {
        return this._feeds.Where(feed => Uri.Equals(feed.Link, feedLink)).Single();
    }
```

due to any of following properties such as 'Id' or 'Link'. That' why I'd rather use `IRepository<T> where T : class` and `IFeedRepository<T> where T : class, IBaseFeed`.

I have been writing an app for Windows 8.1 and unluckily EF is not available. The only wrapper for SQLite that I found is sqlite-net.

`sqlite-net` doesn't contain method `LastInsertId` so I have no idea how to return `T` with the database-generated ID?

Comment: If SQLite-net works like EF, then you don't need a `LastInsertId` method - it should just update your POCO *automagically* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This new code looks much more cohesive, well done!

```
this._feeds = _db.Table<T>().ToList();
```

This is *eager-loading* the table content into your repository class, whenever you instantiate it. What you want is *lazy-loading*, and that's a different ball game - I mean, I would rely on an *object/relational mapper* like [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) to do that gruntwork for me. There must be an EF *provider* for sqlite, for sure.

---

Something about your repository interface `IFeedRepository<T>`, is bothering me. Based on your previous post and this updated code, I believe your interface now looks like this:

```
internal interface IFeedRepository<T> where T : IBaseFeed
{
    int Count { get; }

    void Add(T feed);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T GetFeedById(int id);
    T GetFeedByLink(string feedLink);
    T GetFeedByLink(Uri feedLink);
    int GetFeedIdByLink(string feedLink);
    int GetFeedIdByLink(Uri feedLink);
    void Remove(T feed);
    void RemoveById(int id);
    void Update(T feed);
}
```

I think you're missing an opportunity at a generic repository here:

```
internal interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    int Count { get; }
    T GetById(int it);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Add(T entity);
    void Remove(T entity);
    void RemoveById(int id);
    void Update(T entity);
}
```

And then you could have `IFeedRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class` (I'm not sure what `IBaseFeed` is, but it looks like a superfluous interface), and you can reuse your `IRepository<T>` interface for other "entities".

Just noticed you have `Add(T)` returning `void` - wouldn't it be practical if it returned a `T` with the database-generated ID?

Comment: Edited first post ;)

Comment: I hope you remember my problem ;) https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38901/unit-of-work-with-generic-repository-pattern-mvvm-vol-3