# Unit of Work with Generic Repository Pattern MVVM, vol. 3

Tags: c#, sqlite, mvvm

Continuation of this question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36561/unit-of-work-with-generic-repository-pattern-mvvm-vol-2

I have made some modifications:

- Implement *lazy-loading* (hope so)
- `Add()` and `Update()` returns `T` instead of `void`
- Add `IFeedItemRepository`, `FeedItemRepository`, `IBaseRepository<T>`

**IBaseRepositry**

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    int Count { get; }
    T Add(T entity);
    T GetById(int id);
    T Update(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Remove(T entity);
    void RemoveById(int id);
}
```

**IBaseFeed**

```
public interface IBaseFeed
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
    Uri Link { get; set; }
    string Misc { get; set; }
}
```

**IFeedRepository**

```
internal interface IFeedRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IBaseFeed
{
    int GetFeedIdByLink(string feedLink);
    int GetFeedIdByLink(Uri feedLink);
    T GetByLink(string feedLink);
    T GetByLink(Uri feedLink);
}
```

**FeedRepository**

```
internal class FeedRepository<T> : IFeedRepository<T>, IDisposable
    where T : class, IBaseFeed, new()
{
    private readonly SQLiteConnection _db;
    private Lazy<IList<T>> _feeds;

    private bool _isDisposed = false;

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _feeds.Value.Count;
        }
    }

    public FeedRepository(SQLiteConnection db)
    {
        this._db = db;
        this._feeds = new Lazy<IList<T>>(() => _db.Table<T>().ToList());
    }

    public T Add(T feed)
    {
        this._db.Insert(feed);
        return feed;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return this._feeds.Value;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return this._feeds.Value.Where(feed => int.Equals(feed.Id, id)).Single();
    }

    public T GetByLink(string feedLink)
    {
        return this.GetByLink(new Uri(feedLink));
    }

    public T GetByLink(Uri feedLink)
    {
        return this._feeds.Value.Where(feed => Uri.Equals(feed.Link, feedLink)).Single();
    }

    public int GetFeedIdByLink(string feedLink)
    {
        return this.GetFeedIdByLink(new Uri(feedLink));
    }

    public int GetFeedIdByLink(Uri feedLink)
    {
        return this._feeds.Value.Where(feed => Uri.Equals(feed.Link, feedLink)).Select(feed => feed.Id).Single();
    }

    public void Remove(T feed)
    {
        this._db.Delete(feed);
    }

    public void RemoveById(int id)
    {
        this.Remove(this.GetById(id));
    }

    public T Update(T feed)
    {
        this._db.Update(feed);
        return feed;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (!this._isDisposed)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                if (this._db != null)
                {
                    this._db.Dispose();
                }
            }

            this._isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
```

**IFeedItemRepository**

```
internal interface IFeedItemRepository : IFeedRepository<FeedItem>
{
    IEnumerable<FeedItem> GetFeedItemsByFeedDataId(int feedDataId);
}
```

**FeedItemRepository**

```
internal sealed class FeedItemRepository : FeedRepository<FeedItem>, IFeedItemRepository
{
    public FeedItemRepository(SQLiteConnection db)
        : base(db) { }

    public IEnumerable<FeedItem> GetFeedItemsByFeedDataId(int feedDataId)
    {
        return base.GetAll().Where(feed => int.Equals(feed.FeedDataId, feedDataId));
    }
}
```

**IUnitOfWork**

```
internal interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Commit();
    void Rollback();
}
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private readonly SQLiteConnection _db;

    private IFeedRepository<FeedData> _feedDataRepository;
    private IFeedItemRepository _feedItemRepository;

    private bool _isDisposed = false;

    public IFeedRepository<FeedData> FeedDataRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return _feedDataRepository;
        }
        set
        {
            _feedDataRepository = value;
        }
    }

    public IFeedItemRepository FeedItemRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return _feedItemRepository;
        }
        set
        {
            _feedItemRepository = value;
        }
    }

    public UnitOfWork(SQLiteConnection db)
    {
        this._db = db;
        this._feedDataRepository = new FeedRepository<FeedData>(this._db);
        this._feedItemRepository = new FeedItemRepository(this._db);

        this._db.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        this._db.Commit();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        this._db.Rollback();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (!this._isDisposed)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                if (this._feedDataRepository != null)
                {
                    ((FeedRepository<FeedData>)this._feedDataRepository).Dispose();
                }

                if (this._feedItemRepository != null)
                {
                    ((FeedItemRepository)this._feedItemRepository).Dispose();
                }

                if (this._db != null)
                {
                    this._db.Dispose();
                }
            }

            this._isDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Has the implementation of *lazy-loading* been done correctly?

What about this (UoW):

```
    private IFeedRepository<FeedData> _feedDataRepository;
    private IFeedItemRepository _feedItemRepository;
```

Is it correct?

Is the constructor in `FeedItemRepository` done properly?

Answer (score 2):

Few tiny items:

1. <strike>Can you use an `IDbConnection` interface (or worst case, `DbConnection` class) instead of `SQLiteConnection` for your constructor parameter/class member? This would allow for more generic operation, easier unit testing and easier swap-out of database providers in the future. This is in both the `UnitOfWork` class and the `FeedRepository<T>` class.</strike> Upon further reflection, the way that particular SQLite client library is used, this is unfeasible at this time. Still, I'd recommend a different SQLite client if at all possible which conforms to `IDbConnection`, etc.
2. I would advise against `Dispose()`ing of the `_db` in the `UnitOfWork` class' `Dispose()` method since the class doesn't create it - the caller does. Let the caller `Dispose()` of it. Same goes for the `FeedRepository<T>` class.
3. Do the `FeedDataRepository` and `FeedItemRepository` properties in the `UnitOfWork` class really need setters? It seems dangerous to create them in the constructor and then `Dispose()` them in the `Dispose()` method when someone could come along and change either to something else entirely. You could lose the original references altogether. I'd wager these should be invariant once constructed.

Comment: AFAIK there ISN't different SQLite client for WinRT, am I right?

Comment: Got me on that front. No idea.

Comment: Never mind ;)
I deleted `Dispose()` from Respoitory and UoW should I do anything with setter(3)?

Comment: This was a you-tell-me sort of thing. Do you need the setters? They seemed smelly to me considering the backing fields are created in the class. Are you assigning to them somewhere in client code?

Comment: Grr!!! So stupid mistake! I meant a private set! Is it correct now?

Comment: Same question applies - are you going to set via the property from within the class? Currently, it's not being done. Assignment is only to the backing member variable in the constructor.

Comment: I want only constructor can assignment value to `FeedDataRepository` and `FeedItemRepository`

Comment: Then remove the setters and mark the fields as `readonly`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/K70jq7Wq
Correct?