# Unit of Work with Generic Repository Pattern MVVM, vol. 4

Tags: c#, mvvm

Continuation of this question: [Unit of Work with Generic Repository Pattern MVVM, vol. 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38901/unit-of-work-with-generic-repository-pattern-mvvm-vol-3)

I have made some changes.

- The methods `GetFeedBySomething()` have been replaced by `Find()`
- `GetRepository()` has been added to `UoW`
- I separated `DAL` from `Model`
- `Model` inherits `IBaseEntity` from `DAL` (not sure is it correct)
- `IRepositoryWithId` made `TEntity` to become `IBaseEntity` because I need to have `Id` property. (again not sure is it correct, maybe shall I use `reflection`?)

**This is my code map: [image: Code Map]**

**And here are my code**

**`DAL` CLASSES**

**IRepository**

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    TEntity Add(TEntity entity);
    TEntity Update(TEntity entity);

    IQueryable<TEntity> Find(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();

    void Remove(TEntity entity);
}
```

**IRepositoryWithId**

```
public interface IRepositoryWithId<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IBaseEntity
{
    int Count { get; }

    T GetById(int feedId);

    void RemoveById(int feedId);
}
```

**IBaseEntity**

```
public interface IBaseEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**IFeedRepository**

```
internal class FeedRepository<T> : IRepositoryWithId<T>
    where T : class, IBaseEntity, new()
{
    private readonly SQLiteConnection _dbConnection;
    protected Lazy<IList<T>> _feeds;

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._feeds.IsValueCreated)
                return this._feeds.Value.Count;

            return this._dbConnection.Table<T>().Count();
        }
    }

    public FeedRepository(SQLiteConnection dbConnection)
    {
        this._dbConnection = dbConnection;
        this._feeds = new Lazy<IList<T>>(() => this._dbConnection.Table<T>().ToList());
    }

    public T Add(T feed)
    {
        if (this._feeds.IsValueCreated)
            this._feeds.Value.Add(feed);

        this._dbConnection.Insert(feed);
        return feed;
    }

    public T GetById(int feedId)
    {
        return this._feeds.Value.Where(feed => int.Equals(feed.Id, feedId)).SingleOrDefault();
        //return this._feeds.Value.Where(feed => int.Equals(typeof(T).GetRuntimeProperty("Id").GetValue(feed), feedId)).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public T Update(T feed)
    {
        int indexOfFeed = this.GetIndexOfFeed(feed);
        if (indexOfFeed != -1)
            this._feeds.Value[indexOfFeed] = feed;

        this._dbConnection.Update(feed);

        return feed;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return this._feeds.Value;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Find(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (predicate != null)
            return this._feeds.Value.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);

        return this._feeds.Value.AsQueryable();
    }

    public void Remove(T feed)
    {
        int indexOfFeed = this.GetIndexOfFeed(feed);
        if (indexOfFeed != -1)
            this._feeds.Value.RemoveAt(indexOfFeed);

        this._dbConnection.Delete(feed);
    }

    public void RemoveById(int feedId)
    {
        T feed = this.GetById(feedId);

        if (feed != null)
            this.Remove(this.GetById(feedId));
    }

    private int GetIndexOfFeed(T feed)
    {
        if (this._feeds.IsValueCreated)
        {
            //int id = (int)typeof(T).GetRuntimeProperty("Id").GetValue(feed);
            int indexOfFeed = this._feeds.Value.IndexOf(this.GetById(feed.Id));

            return indexOfFeed;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

**IUnitOfWork**

```
internal interface IUnitOfWork
{
    bool IsInTransaction { get; }

    IRepositoryWithId<TEntity> GetFeedRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity, new();

    void Commit();
    void Rollback();
}
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly SQLiteConnection _dbConnection;
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _repositories;

    public bool IsInTransaction
    {
        get { return this._dbConnection.IsInTransaction; }
    }

    public UnitOfWork(SQLiteConnection dbConnection)
    {
        this._repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        this._dbConnection = dbConnection;
        this._dbConnection.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public IRepositoryWithId<TEntity> GetFeedRepository<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity, new()
    {
        if (this._repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)))
            return this._repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as IRepositoryWithId<TEntity>;

        var repository = new FeedRepository<TEntity>(this._dbConnection);

        this._repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repository);

        return repository;
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        this._dbConnection.Commit();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        this._dbConnection.Rollback();
    }
}
```

**`MODEL` CLASSES**

**IFeed**

```
public interface IFeed : IBaseEntity
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    Uri Link { get; set; }
    DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
}
```

**FeedData and FeedItem**

```
public sealed class FeedData : IFeed, INotifyPropertyChanged { }
public sealed class FeedItem : IFeed, INotifyPropertyChanged { }
```

And now I have some questions about:

- `IBaseEntity` is it necessary or shall I use `reflection`

Answer (score 5):

Use `IBaseEntity`, reflection should never be used unless you really need to.

I'm not a fan of returning a not executed `IQueryable<>` as you do in your `Find` method, you should consider executing the query and returning the `IEnumerable<>`, otherwise you expose yourself to potential bugs (If the client of the method messes up with the query) and it is harder to debug after since you might not know when is your query executed.

You should consider commenting your code, one day you will be happy you did it!

I'm not sure why your generic repository is named `FeedRepository`, maybe it's because it has a meaning I don't understand in english but you might want to rename it in a more generic way (Say... `SqLiteRepository` since it is an implementation of your interface for an SqlLite data access).